# Flutter Video_player not playing rtsp stream

Tags: flutter, rtsp, flutter-video-player

I am trying to play the rtsp in my flutter app using this plugin [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) but this is showing Player Exception how to play rtsp only using this video player?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried flutter_vlc_player for better rtsp support?

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player

I had a combo of rtmp, rtsp, http mp4 clips and http motion jpeg and flutter_vlc_player handles them. I think video_player just doesn't do everything.

Comment: but it it not supporting the full screen